# JSON parsing Issues Redux

Tags: java, android, json, parsing

I had issues in the past with parsing my JSON code, and I almost had it and lost all my code changes.  I am putting here the guts of it getting my JSON (which I have verified it gets fine).  It's just the parsing of it...I need to get the "fulltext" field and I guess put it into an array...

```
try {

            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "UTF-8"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            result = sb.toString();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("log_tag" , "Error converting result " + e.toString());
        }

        try{

            JSONObject rootobject = new JSONObject(result).getJSONObject("query").getJSONObject("results");


        } catch (JSONException e){
            Log.e("JSON Parser", Log.getStackTraceString(e));
            e.printStackTrace();
        }



        return null;
```

Within this, the JSONObject area I believe is incorrect.  I need to iterate over all of the JSON objects getting the "fulltext" value from all of them and eventually putting them into the database.  I'm drawing the team names from this website.

In my mind, I should be able to use

```
String teamname = rootobject.getString("fulltext");
```

in some way.  I have tried this, but it doesn't work at all.  In fact I get the error message "No value for fulltext" when I check the error logs.

I know I'm going wrong somewhere but can't quite place it.  I'm still confused with JSON parsing and whatnot but I'm determined to get there.

This is a link to the sample JSON (the URL that I'm accessing)

```
http://bit.ly/1JnlSck
```

My apologies for forgetting this in the first post.

Comment: The fact that we can't see the JSON itself makes it basically impossible to help you. A short but complete program demonstrating the problem, including the JSON, would really help...

Comment: it is very unlikely that you are able to call `jsonTextView.setText("It has read the data");` and `reader.readLine()` in the same method, as that would be in the same thread, which would mean that one of those 2 calls is not on the correct thread.

Comment: I have updated to add the URL link to the JSON..

Comment: njzk2 : I had that in there as a test and is not necessary..I simply forgot to remove it before posting.  It has now been removed

Comment: It would be a whole lot easier for you if "results" was a JSONArray instead of a JSONObject containing multiple JSONObjects.

Comment: Agreed that it would be easier.  This is not my JSON but comes from a website who I'm writing the app to complement so I cannot change the JSON format...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably should do is restructure your JSON. Currently you have it like this...

```
"results": {
    "Team:\"Die Unglaublichen\"": {
        "printouts": [],
        "fulltext": "Team:\"Die Unglaublichen\"",
        "fullurl": "http://wiki.planetkubb.com/wiki/Team:%22Die_Unglaublichen%22",
        "namespace": 822,
        "exists": true
    },
    "Team:(Can't Stand) Le Kubb Bricks": {
        "printouts": [],
        "fulltext": "Team:(Can't Stand) Le Kubb Bricks",
        "fullurl": "http://wiki.planetkubb.com/wiki/Team:(Can%27t_Stand)_Le_Kubb_Bricks",
        "namespace": 822,
        "exists": true
    }
}
```

... where "results" is a JSONObject containing several child JSONObjects. If you can rework it so that "results" is a JSONArray containing JSONObjects, like so...

```
"results": [
    {
        "Team": "Die Unglaublichen",
        "printouts": [],
        "fulltext": "Team:\"Die Unglaublichen\"",
        "fullurl": "http://wiki.planetkubb.com/wiki/Team:%22Die_Unglaublichen%22",
        "namespace": 822,
        "exists": true
    },
    {
        "Team": "(Can't Stand) Le Kubb Bricks",
        "printouts": [],
        "fulltext": "Team:(Can't Stand) Le Kubb Bricks",
        "fullurl": "http://wiki.planetkubb.com/wiki/Team:(Can%27t_Stand)_Le_Kubb_Bricks",
        "namespace": 822,
        "exists": true
    }
]
```

... then you can loop through the "results" array and get each of its JSONObjects and any name/values you wish:

```
try {
    JSONArray resultsArray = rootObject.getJSONArray("results");
    for (int i = 0; i < resultsArray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject teamObject = resultsArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String fullText = teamObject.getString("fulltext");
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't my JSON, I'm grabbing this from a partner website that I'm writing the app for...